# findViewById on my EditText returns null error

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently a new learner to kotlin and android studio in general, and while creating my app, I wanted to make an editable text box in my activity, and so I initialized my text box like so

```
val testingbox: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTexttest)
```

However, when I press my pushbutton that changes the activity to the next one, I crash my app. So when I went to look at my logcat, it gave me this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.editTexttest) must not be null
```

Initialising my buttons like how I did with the text box seemed to have no errors. Are there any differences between the 2? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the xml, so that we can confirm id is true?

Comment: Because there is no editText with the given id, so `findViewById` returns null and, but the declare variable is non-null type hence you get NullPointer

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTexttest"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

Comment: I ctrl clicked the address on the code and it also brought me to the xml page. This should mean that the id on the code is correct, yes?